# Automation Trigger Options

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

We currently trigger automations via a file drop to a FTP Location. This works well as the file drops, processes and waits until 9am before it sends the mail.

Sometimes are file drops are late and the only way to kick the automation off is to stop it, change the time to a later time, re-drop the file and change the time back to 9am once the automation has completed.

Is there an alternate way to kick the automation off, should the file drop be late?